# Usage of the "SAP Function OCX"

Tags: .net, interop, sap-gui, saprfc

Does it make sense to use the "SAP Function Control" (`wdtlog.ocx`  in connection with `wdtlog.ocx` and `wdtaocx.ocx`)  to access (via the Interop-Assemblys `SAPFunctionsOCX.dll`, `SAPLogonCtrl.dll` and `SAPTableFactoryCtrl.dll`) to SAP with RFCs instead of the no longer supported SAP .NET Connector of .NET ?

I know there is also the product **ERPConnect** of the company "Theobald Software", but I only need RFC access !

Does anybody know, if these controls will also be supported in the future for SAP ECC 6.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAP customers are quite notorious about "certified interfaces". If you use something that is not clearly supported by SAP then you should rather not use it. I think this applies for these controls: Aren't they part of the COM Connector that is no longer supported?

If you can help it use web services. If not consider to buy some RFC wrapper or make one yourself...

Answer (score 0):

This is rather old, but as search engines might still find this, here is some more info on this:

Since the question had been asked, SAP meanwhile released a new version of the SAP Connector for .NET: https://support.sap.com/connectors

The ocx controls you mention above are also still part of the latest 7.50 SAPGui release, so should also remain with us for quite some time to come.